# When can corp trash its own ice?

Tags: android-netrunner

[The Rules (page 13) say:](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/android-netrunner-core-rules.pdf)

> When installing a card in a server, the Corporation can first 
>   trash any cards already installed in that server.

And also:

> When installing ice, the Corporation can first trash any ice 
>   protecting that server in order to reduce the install cost.

The first quote seems to imply that when the corp is installing *any* card in a server (including Agenda, Asset or Upgrade), it can trash any card installed on the same server first, including ice.

The second quote is more restrictive, but doesn't seem to actually contradict the first one.

At the same time, [I have seen comments](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11692/can-the-runner-corporation-trash-their-own-installed-cards#comment20296_11693) indicating that the corp can't trash ice when installing other card types.

So, can the corp actually trash ice when installing other types of cards?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, ice can only be trashed when installing other ice.**

The terms "in a server" and "protecting a server" are not interchangeable, but rather used discretely to refer to different types of cards and their relation to servers. Agendas, assets, and upgrades are installed *in* servers, while ice is always referred to as *protecting* a server, and is never considered to be *in* a server for the purposes of any rules or card effects.

Answer (score 0):

Ice is not installed *in* a server, ice is installed protecting a server. Only assets, agendas and upgrades are installed in the server itself. This also mattered for cards like [Estelle Moon](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/13032), since ice was not in the server, she did not trigger.